# Shouldn't NestJS exception filters catch event emitter errors?

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs

I'm running some manual tests on a NestJS application I'm refactoring and just found an odd behaviour from nest's global exception filter.
The developer who created this project used this as a exception filter:

```js
import {
  ExceptionFilter,
  Catch,
  ArgumentsHost,
  HttpException,
  HttpStatus,
} from '@nestjs/common';
import { HttpAdapterHost } from '@nestjs/core';
import { LoggerService } from '../../config/logger.service';

@Catch()
export class GlobalExceptionsFilter implements ExceptionFilter {
  constructor(
    private readonly httpAdapterHost: HttpAdapterHost,
    private readonly logger: LoggerService,
  ) {}

  catch(exception: Error, host: ArgumentsHost): void {
    const { httpAdapter } = this.httpAdapterHost;

    const ctx = host.switchToHttp();

    const httpStatus =
      exception instanceof HttpException
        ? exception.getStatus()
        : HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;

    const responseBody = {
      statusCode: httpStatus,
      path: httpAdapter.getRequestUrl(ctx.getRequest()),
      cause: `${exception.name}: ${exception.message}`,
      timestamp: new Date().toISOString(),
    };

    this.logger.error(responseBody?.cause);

    httpAdapter.reply(ctx.getResponse(), responseBody, httpStatus);
  }
}
```

Which is almost exactly the same catch-everything filter example in [Nest's docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/exception-filters), so it's very generic, indeed.

In a certain part of this project, there's a controller with something like this:

```js
  @OnEvent(Events.POTATO_EVENT)
  async potatoMethod(payload) {
    return await this.service.potatoMethod(payload);
```

Currently, there's no payload validation on the service's `potatoMethod`, so the controller receives a payload from another service using `EventEmitter2` and forwards it to it's service, which then tries to fetch a record on the database by calling an ORM method.
If `payload.potatoNumber` is sent correctly, nothing wrong happens, but if I send `payload.potatoNumber` as undefined, the ORM will throw an error that will not be caught on that global filter.
The same thing doesn't happen if instead of using a `@OnEvent()` I just use a `@Get()` directly on the controller to turn it into an endpoint.

Currently, `main` looks something like this:

```js
(async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  await app.listen(3000);
})();
```

I might be completely wrong, but this should only happen if the application is not using `NestFactory.createMicroservice()` on it's `main.ts` file, right? If positive, how exactly does [microservices](https://docs.nestjs.com/microservices/basics) work natively in Nest?

Answer (score 0):

I was also caught a bit off guard with this behaviour in **nestjs event emitter 1.4.1**, but at the same time it  makes sense it happens unless you handle those exceptions yourself.

But they ended up adding that type of handling in https://github.com/nestjs/event-emitter/pull/908, so you just need to update to event emitter 2.0.1 or greater (2.0.4 at the time of this answer).